# JavaScript - Remove everything after </html> tag

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how to write javascript code that removes everything after the html tag.

I have the following file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
// my script
</script>
</head>
<body>
Some text
</body>
</html>
<script>
</script>
```

Rendered output must not contain the last script (or any other) tag.

Comment: Why would you have anything outside of HTML tag?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Are you trying to remove the ads that places like geocities put on your free website?

Comment: @šljaker maybe you read somewhere that script tags should be at the end of the file, that is true but just before `</html>` tag

Comment: I found how to do it I just need to refine my code first.

Comment: I have your answer posted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code waits for the page to load and then removes all tags after the `</html>` try it with firebug and you will see. You need to create a place holder as such in this example `<div id="last"></div>` after your last tag and then it removes the rest of the tags.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function()
        {
        var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var found=false;
        var cur=0;
        for(var i=0; i<body.childNodes.length; i++)
        {
            if(body.childNodes[i].id=='last')
            {
                cur=i;
                found=true;
            }
            else if(found && i>cur+1)
            {
                body.removeChild(body.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       Some text
       <div id="last">

       </div>
    </body>
</html>
<p>
Im not gonna show
</p>
<input/>
<script>
</script>
<b>
</b>
```

Don't forget to scroll! Enjoy!

Oddly enought the formating of code here is not functioning right. Its probably my fault.

Edit renamed my variable to `body`

Comment: if the "<p>" element is placed outside the "<html>" element, how can it be considered a "child element" of that element? This is semantically confusing. Although your solution might work (I've not tested it), I don't think it relies on standards :(

Comment: Heh, fair enough! You still need to mark the end of the *real* html though. I guess the guy wanted this to remove adverts or similar on free hosting so this might well work.

Comment: @ XpiritO The reason why its a child element is that modern browsers as rq said place the tags in the body. I took this to my advantage and removed them after the div id="last" placeholder I added. Actually my variable `html` is actually the body tag, sorry for the bad naming.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the DOM, outside of HTML there is nothing. Your closing `</html>` gets moved to account for the badly formatted HTML. Here is how [firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29) shows your example.

[image: In firebug]

This means that from javascript, there is no way to know *which* markup was after the html.

Comment: Its still possible to do what he wants.

Comment: Well I should thank you as your answer lead me to my answer as I did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    document.close();
    document.open();
    document.write("<html></html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Trackers are usually added during the transfer to the client-side by the website server.
 They place their code like this:
     **</html>***<script>(function tracker(){In Here})</script>*
The browser changes it to this:
      *<script>(function tracker(){In Here})</script>*
  **</body>
</html>**

---

So if you just put <!-- after the </html> so it looks like this, shown below with the tracker added
 </html>**<!--***<script>(function tracker(){In Here})</script>*
The browser will changes it all to a comment by adding the closing tag:
</html>**<!--***<script>function tracker(){In Here}</script>***-->**
*The tracker script just becomes a comment and stay's outside the html where it will not function!*

---

This is the reason why some code can be after the website's last tag!
 Why block it? 1 tracker can bring in hundreds if they want! All on the client's-side internet connection! Where your code gets blamed for the third party actions!

---

If you want to use Javascript to delete the code put an opening tag for a div and give it an ID also add the opening comment tag like this:
**</html><div id='deleteThis'><!--***<script>function tracker(){In Here}</script>*
The browser changes it by closing the comment and div tags:
     **<div id='deleteThis'>**
        **<!--***<script>(function tracker(){In Here})</script>***-->**
     **</div>**
**</body>**
**</html>**
Tracker-Script should not function but still add in your script-code:
function deleteTracker(){ document.getElementByID('deleteThis').innerHTML="";}
 Run as soon as possible, so you should add to the body tag! <body onload='deleteTracker()'>
Everything inside the div will be deleted!